# Create Integer List of Lists in C

Tags: c, list, integer

I would like to create an integer list in C containing integer arrays of variable size. The length of the main list will not need to change.

How would I declare it - my implementation - particularly my access is not working:

```
int dataArray[length];
int dataArray[0] = [1,2,3];
int dataArray[1] = [5,6];
.
.
.
populate

for(int a = 0; a<sizeof(dataArray); a++) {
   tempArr = dataArray[a];
   for(into = 0; b>sizeof(tempArr); b++) {
      print(dataArray[a][b])
   }
}
```

Comment: What is not working ? Does it not compile ? Does it not run ? Did it format your hard drive ? What is `print` ?

Comment: Unless you're planning on *guessing* the length of those variable-length arrays at some time later when you plan on using them, you likely want to create an array of `struct` where the structure is something like `struct IList { size_t length; int *values; }`.

Answer (score 1):

Your main array needs to hold pointers to other arrays. Therefore it should not be `int dataArray[length]` but rather `int* dataArray[length]` this means it will hold `length` amount of references to integer arrays.

```
int* array[length];

int randomSizeArray[x];
randomSizeArray[0] = 1;
.
.
.
randomSizeArray[x] = 5;
int* array[0] = randomSizeArray;
```

Also `sizeof()` will not work the way you expect it to - in C you need to store separately how many elements are in an array. I'd recommend reading a C tutorial from the ground up as you seem to have shaky knowledge of basics.

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof` results in the byte count not element count.

Divide the array size by the element size to find the element count.

```
int dataArray[length];
int dataArray[0] = [1,2,3];
int dataArray[1] = [5,6];
...

// for(int a = 0; a<sizeof(dataArray); a++) {
for(size_t a = 0; a<sizeof(dataArray)/sizeof(dataArray[0]); a++) {
   tempArr = dataArray[a];
   // for(into = 0; b>sizeof(tempArr); b++) {
   for(into = 0; b>sizeof(tempArr)/sizeof(tempArr[0]); b++) {

   // or do you really want
   // for(size_t = 0; b<sizeof(tempArr)/sizeof(tempArr[0]); b++) {

      print(dataArray[a][b])
   }
}
```